# Auto configure private DNS resolve in VPC network for EC2 instances running from AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have AMI template server in EC2 AWS witch run my server.
For sure it's running in single VPC network.
I want to be able to connect any my server using ssh once it's running using hostname dns resolve.

For example I have **gateway**, **server-01**, **server-02** in my ec2 instances list.
Once I launch one more server from my AMI (**server-03**), I need to connect to it from **gateway** server using ***ssh server-03***

How I can do it?

Comment: What is your specific issue? Any errors?

Comment: I have set hostname on each of my servers, but it don't work. I just can't search any working solution in google yet.

Comment: Your question lacks details. What exactly are your security groups, VPC setup, etc... ?

Comment: I have most common and simple setup for it, just to work with. I just searching a solution to convenient moving between instances.

Comment: Clearly your "most common" is incorrect. Unless you provide all the relevant details, its basically impossible to speculate on why you have connection issues.

Comment: But I don't have any connection issue. I just use **ssh <private IP>** for moving between instances. I need to make from scratch the dns resolving for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using terraform to manage your EC2 instances. This will allow you to do many things you would normally do manually.

You can have a private or public hosted zone assigned to your VPCs (public would require a bit more)

Then on terraform, you can have the following:

- Your ec2 instance creation.
- A tfvar file containing the variables for all your EC2 instances
- Your Hosted Zone attaching the EC2 private IP to a DNS
- Output afterwards to print out your new EC2 instance with the private DNS you can SSH to